# Import-PfxCertificate not importing to correct certificate store

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate, openssl

I am trying to import a PFX using PowerShell, that has been created by OpenSSL from a cer and key file (the key was generated by OpenSSL along with a CSR, which was submitted to internal AD CA to generate the cer)

When viewing cert info in OpenSSL, I can see the PFX contains just a single cert and a private key, which is what I expect

If I run the below command, the cert is imported into intermediate certificate authorities, rather than the machine personal store as I have specified:

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $SharedPFXPath -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $PFXPassword -AsPlainText -Force) -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Exportable
```

What could be the reason the `Import-PfxCertificate` command might be ignoring my cert store location?

**EDIT**: Just for some additional info, I thought I'd detail the commands used to generate the source cert and key files etc:

Start by creating a key and CSR

```
openssl.exe genrsa -out $KeyFilePath 2048
openssl.exe req -new -key $KeyFilePath -out $CSROutputPath -config $ConfigFilePath
```

The CSR config file contains this (actual DN values removed):

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = req_ext
prompt = no

[req_distinguished_name]
C = COUNTRY CODE
ST = COUNTY/STATE
L = TOWN
O = ORG
OU = OU
CN = COMMON NAME

[req_ext]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = SAN
```

Then I submit the CSR to AD CA, and save the BASE64 encoded cert. I use this and the key file to create the PFX

```
openssl.exe pkcs12 -export -in $CertPath -inkey $KeyFilePath -out $PFXPath -passout pass:$PFXPassword -nomac
```

I had to add `-nomac` to my PFX command, as otherwise I got an incorrect password error every time I tried to manually import the PFX into the cert store. Not sure if this would contribute to my issue, or if some of my earlier commands might be causing me some problems?

Comment: What happens if you `cd` into the store first, then run it without the `-CertStoreLocation` argument? (I'm clutching at straws here, by the way!)

Comment: Sadly it does the same thing

Comment: The cert does not seem to have the Basic Constraints extension, so no I don't think so

Comment: Any way we can do a cert exchange to compare? I wonder if our AD CA is doing something unusual in the Web Server template that means my cert is interpreted differently to yours when imported. My team doesn't control the CA or templates, so if there is an issue there I'd need to identify it before I approach the team to adjust it

Comment: Got it thanks!
I'll have a play and see what happens when using yours. Interestingly, if I run my same PS command on my Win 10 workstation, it imports correctly to personal, so I am wondering if this is a Server 2016 issue specifically

Comment: Ok, don't know why, but if I add this to my command, it works flawlessly; `-certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -nomac`

Comment: That is very odd.  My PFX was created with OpenSSL version 1.1.1n on Linux.  That may have a bearing.  Anyway, glad you got somewhere.

Comment: Yeah I'm using 3.0 on Windows. I've seen other questions around the password issue during import which I also had, but didn't realise this would also play into the import/store issue. References here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343254/the-password-you-entered-is-incorrect-when-importing-pfx-files-to-windows-cer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is linked to similar issues mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343254/the-password-you-entered-is-incorrect-when-importing-pfx-files-to-windows-cer)

I am using OpenSSL 3.0 on Windows to generate my certs and PFXs etc. and whilst I had the same "Incorrect Password" issue as this other question, which was resolved by adding `-nomac`, I had not added the other options.

After adding `-certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES` to my PFX export command, I no longer have any issues and my cert is imported into my specified store